# Retrieve the value stored in a multiset

Tags: c++, c++11, multiset

I am trying to retrieve the value that is stored in a particular spot in a mulitset, but all I'm unable to find out how to do that anywhere online. This is also my first time using multisets in C++.

The multiset that I want to get the value from is the numerator, and it's declared in the header file that I attached to my program. Below is what I have tried.

```
// This method will swap the numerator and denominator values
void Fraction::Invert() {
    int tmp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)numerator.size(); i++) {
        // I want the value stored in the multiset (numerator) at i
        tmp = numerator.find(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you wish to swap the complete contents of the two multisets, there's always [swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/swap) (the whole thing would be `numerator.swap(denominator);`). Otherwise your code is not all that clear. Please make a proper [mre] and expand your explanation what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: I just edited the question to help make it more clear. I just want to know how to get the value stored in the multiset (named numerator) at i.

Comment: A multiset is a tree, what's `i` in a tree? [XY problem?](https://xyproblem.info/) What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: i is my iterator in my for loop, is there a way to get the value, just like I can with a vector?

Comment: "first time" -- can you elaborate on that? `find()` doesn't do what you think it does. I assume you're learning multisets and the rest of the C++ library, from a quality C++ textbook. So, you must've misunderstood something in your textbook's explanation of `find`. Can you briefly quote how your textbook describes this function, and let's clear up your misunderstanding!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I found online that find returns an iterator pointing to an element stored in the multiset. which is not what I want, I want the value at that point.

Comment: Correct, to get that you want to dereference the iterator. But there are many more issues here. `find`'s parameter isn't what the shown code thinks it was. Multisets are not designed to be accessed "by position". One could obtain the beginning iterator and `advance` it, I suppose. But that would be quite an absurd thing to do. This is not what multisets are for. See, C++ is just to complicated and it's just not possible to learn it one search engine query at a time. The complete technical specifications to C++ run for about two thousand pages. That's a lot of searching.

Comment: I really think you should read the XY problem link. You seem to be stuck on the details of your attempted solution which may or may not be a way to solve your actual problem. Continuing in this way is likely to use up more effort on all sides than if you took a step back and described the real problem you are solving.

Comment: @codeblue I add some answer, if you like this is your answer, please accept it

Comment: please be aware, that you are using multiset, which can contain multiple equal elements. Find() is only returning an iterator to ONE of them if existing.
if you need to get ALL of the matching elements, you have to use multiset::equal_range()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many methods exist so you can retrieve a value from a multiset.

**First:**

You can use an *iterator*. Something like below:

```
    for (auto cit = numerator.cbegin(); cit != numerator.cend(); cit++)
        std::cout << *cit << std::endl;
```

In the your example, it is like below:

```
// This method will swap the numerator and denominator values
void Fraction::Invert() {
    int tmp = 0;

    auto cit = numerator.cbegin();
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)numerator.size() && cit != numerator.cend(); i++, cit++) {
        // I want the value stored in the multiset (numerator) at i
        tmp = *cit; // *cit is the value of i'th number of multiset
    }
}
```

**Second:**

You can use the range *for* style:

```
    for (auto value : numerator)
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
```

And in the your example, it is like below:

```
// This method will swap the numerator and denominator values
void Fraction::Invert() {
    int tmp = 0;

    int i = 0;
    for (auto value : numerator) {
        // I want the value stored in the multiset (numerator) at i
        tmp = value; // value is the value of i'th number of multiset
        ++i;
    }
}
```